# How do I stop PHP DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile from generating hex codes, or modify the rest of my file

Tags: java, php

How do I stop PHP DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile from generating hex codes, transforming this

```
<a href="word word\word.html"></a>
```

into this

```
<a href="word%20word%5Cword.html"></a>
```

It also adds a meta tag and appends quotation marks on my id's and other attributes that don't need it..., but this is the actual problem since it breaks the links which stop working

I'm loading an html file, adding a header from another file, and saving it. I've narrowed the problem to DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile alone

EDIT 1: On my local site I get "The requested URL was not found on this server" although it's displayed as mysite\word word\word.html in the address bar. If I go to the address bar an tap enter it works again. If I copy paste word%20word%5Cword.html, it's transformed in the address bar to word word\word.html, but throws "The requested URL was not found on this server". If I tap enter again in the address bar, then it works. Clearly word%20word%5Cword.html doesn't work...  and the smart browser is FF. UC leaves it with hex codes so it can never work, Chrome also...

EDIT 2: Even weirder, the problem is not %20, but only the %5c... which true, it's an "`\`" not an "/" which the browser fixes... and actually I suppose I can't narrow the problem to saveHTMLFile since when I test in browser the hex code appears to change back to the corresponding character, only it breaks functionality. Suppose one fix is to change all "`\`" to "/", but I really don't want saveHTMLFile changing anything because it also goes into my human readable html comments and makes a mess by replacing stuff with html entities, that's just pointless from the html format viewpoint. Of course the final fix is go back to plain file and strings manipulation, but for the sake of the effort up to here I'ld like to stop saveHTMLFile transforming my html

EDIT 3: On a file compare manual inspection I realize this is far worse... multiple `\"` dissapeared entirely while others did not, as well as `,` from my <meta name="description" tag. I cannot imagine what business it had with those. It removed trailing `/` from my relative paths also. This is inadmissible, and this kind of implementation makes me wanna pray for genocidal aliens to find us =]. If I can't stop it messing my file it's back to plain old safe file manipulation. This is PHP 5.3.1. I'll try a slightly newer one

EDIT 4: same problems in PHP 5.4.7

Comment: There is nothing to fix, it works as expected. The white space, the backspace character (``\``) and about a dozen other characters have special meaning in URLs. In order to represent themselves they must be encoded using `%` followed by two hex digits representing their ASCII code.

Comment: I have to echo @axiac. It's working as expected, those need to be there. An alternative is to use `DOMDocument::saveHTML` instead and search and replace before saving.

Comment: @axiac, what do you mean by "it works". On my local site I get "The requested URL was not found on this server" although it's displayed as mysite\word word\word.html in the address bar. If I go to the address bar an tap enter it works again. If I copy paste word%20word%5Cword.html, it's transformed in the address bar to word word\word.html, but throws "The requested URL was not found on this server". If I tap enter again in the address bar, then it works. Clearly word%20word%5Cword.html doesn't work...

Comment: post your php code for you are generating it.  It looks like when you set the href attribute it is URL encoding the string.  It would probably be fixed if you just change the "\" to a "/".

Comment: @Clay, that's why I said I narrowed the problem down to saveHTMLFile because loadHTML doesn't cause the problem. The essential code is: `@$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);$frag = $dom->createCDATASection(file_get_contents("header.html"));$body->insertBefore($frag, $firstChild);$dom->saveHTMLFile($file);`The URL which gets hex coded is not part of the header, is part of the original html

Comment: Actually I can't check which function causes the problems (see edits in main post), and it's irrelevant. I suppose both since trying this didn't help at all ` $original = $dom->createCDATASection(file_get_contents($file));  $dom->loadHTML($original->data);` Changing PHP version didn't help either. I'm appalled, wouldn't have imagined implementation this bad could exist, as I've discovered far more problems...

Comment: Do not use backslashes (``\``) to separate the path components. URLs use forward slashes (`/`) for this purposes. When asked for `a\b.html`, maybe a web server that runs on Windows is able to find the `b.html` file in the `a` directory but on all the other OS-es it will try to find a file named `a\b.html` and it will fail. `DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile()` is not broken, your HTML is.

Comment: @axiac, how is my HTML broken if saveHTMLFile removes colons from the middle of atribute values with no HTML value whatsoever, only some of slash-quotes, removes trailing backslashes from relative paths to start relative path from site's root (which work then don't), and replacing my HTML comments content with HTML entities garbling it, making it unreadable? Read all the original post before answering.

Comment: I'm quitting PHP in favor of Java since clearly the implementors have mental issues. Not only that but hosts for instance sometime require me to use absolute paths instead of one built from their $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT], so both PHP and community are unreliable and do not respect the trade. It's common sense when implementing a file manipulating function, to give the option from the start to the user to change nothing else than the user's requested changes. My HTML worked, thus didn't need hex codes, then after it had hex codes, it stopped working. Also BTW, URL is not HTML specification.

Comment: Final comment, the other save file functions of DOMDocument also garble the file they save, adding or removing stuff, also related to encoding. This implementation respects nothing. If you know your class has encoding issues, make members for the user to specify. In the docs however the encoding options appear readonly, but only one is, and none work anyway. Everywhere Iread people "hack" then don't get a fix anyway. Unacceptable. This is PHP 5.4 not 0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came upon in Java a library called Jsoup, which decapitalized some of my text and removed ending tags it shouldn't. There's at least two more Java DOM implementations I could try but guess I have to stay away from DOM implementations altogether, I'm beginning to see a pattern here =]. There's something fundamentally wrong when programmers can't implement basic text parsing consistent with specification - speaking of which, Jsoup does not produce hex codes... just saying

Simple solution is file manipulation (Java) - avoid the problem altogether and Keep It Simple Stupid:

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File(testfilepath);
htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
header = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(headerfilepath));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<body(.*)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
String match = null;
                if (matcher.find())
                    match = matcher.group();
                else {
                    System.out.println("no body in file: " + htmlFile);
                    continue;
                }
htmlString = htmlString.replaceFirst(pattern.toString(), match + header);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(htmlTemplateFile, htmlString);
```